# Should I pick my tables up by hand?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I need to move a crafting table, chest, and/or furnaces, I usually use my tools.  I end up moving those items a lot as I change the layout of my place / mine from time to time.  I also know mining/ digging/etc wears on that tool so:

Does picking up the those items wear on my tools?

Should I move those items by hand or use the tools?

I hate breaking my tools! I want them to last forever!

Comment: pretty sure it's 2 uses for every tool, so it's best to use your hand, but I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Chests and Crafting tables** only take a few seconds to break with your hands, so if you want to save on your tools that would be a good idea (although stone tools are very cheap and easy to make, and have 132 uses).

**Furnaces** on the other hand are not possible to "mine" without a tool (you will break it eventually, but nothing will drop), and is definitely worth one use of your pickaxe.

Using a tool on the appropriate type of block consumes one use of it, using it on something else consumes two uses. Axe for wood, pickaxe for stone, etc.

Answer (score 6):

An alternate solution, as I never move my chests or tables:

I always create a new set (furnace, crafting table and chest) wherever I set a new "safe-house" or area to work in.

This just means I can work wherever I am, and they don't take a lot of resources to make.